# VLOOKUP MATCH Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, vlookup

I have a worksheet of data (sheet 1) with around 1000 reference numbers (reference numbers ex `dea564ee45bf47ddb156806528eeb4d5`). On another sheet (sheet 2) I have a shorter ~20 list of reference numbers that have been responded to.

I want to enter a formula that will lookup the reference number found on sheet 1 and output a Yes or No (whether or not they have been responded to) based on the list on sheet 2.

I have tried MATCH and VLOOKUP functions with no luck.

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(cellinsheet1,sheet2table,1),"Yes","No")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the forth criterion and ask if an error is pulled back:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(cellinsheet1,sheet2table,1,FALSE)),"No","Yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

*Your formula needs little correction which has been shown by @Scott Craner, as an alternative you may use this one also.*

[image]

- Formula in Sheet 2 cell U2:

  ```
  =IF(ISBLANK(S2),"",IFERROR(IF(MATCH(S2,Sheet1!$P2:$P6,0),"Yes",),"No"))
  ```
- *You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*